# Updating term in Term Store not updating list column

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store

I'm using SPO, and attempting to set up term store to give a folderless method to search for documents but I've hit a problem. In term store I have a set of terms. These are being utilised in a SharePoint Library as Managed Metadata columns.

There is a need to change one of the terms. Navigating to site Site Settings> Term Store Management Tool I an edit the 'Default Label' of the tag. Once completed and saved, I test by navigating back to the Library, add a new document, add a tag from the informatation pane, (where I can see the renamed tag). Once tag is assigned it defaults to the old name.
[image]

I waited over 48 hours but it still gives me the old tag when I assign it to a document.

Answer (score 0):

There is a hidden list and a periodic job that runs on the "server" to update those labels at a site level. It sounds like you've waited long enough though. It might be worth a support ticket if it still hasn't updated.

Before you do that though, try recreating your library on a fresh new site. Add a document and verify the term's label is updated as you expect. Once you've verified this you can delete the site.